# Unexpected NULL return of HQL subqueries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, hql

I have done my OR mapping by using NHibernate in my C# web application. When i want to get all leaf nodes, i use a query statement like this:

```
List<NODE> LeafList =(List<NODE>) Session.CreateQuery("from NODE as node where node.Id not in (select FatherNodeId from NODE)").List<NODE>();
```

However, i get the count of LeafList equals to 0 after the query. My database is like:

```
Id FatherNodeId
1   NULL
3    1
4    3
5    3
```

So, my expected result should be nodes whose id is 4 or 5.
What’s more confusing, if i change "not in" to "in", the query works well, and return nodes whose id is 1 or 3.

So whats wrong with my not in subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Not exist` key word

Try this .

```
from NODE as node where node.Id not exists ( select  FatherNodeId from NODE)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But when i try to use not exists, it encountered a sql syntax error unfortunately. So.. this maybe not the reason

Answer (score 0):

> So whats wrong with my not in subqueries ?

This is a very important question because, once known, this issue should never be forgotten when working with NULL values.

The problem is not with NH or .Net. It is with the semantics of boolean expression involving NULL.
Any boolean expression involving NULL will never be true (which does not mean at all it will always be false) and any expression involving the result will never be true.

So these queries, which where clauses seem always true, never return any result, because they never resolve to true :

```
select 1 where (null=null) or not(null=null)

select 1 where (1=null) or not(1=null)

select 1 where (1<>null) or not(1<>null)
```

Your query should be something like this (not really familiar with HQL)

```
from NODE as node 
    where not exists 
        ( from NODE as child where child.FatherNodeId = node.Id )
```